# Create a Func<> with Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Inspired by [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/lichen/archive/2013/10/08/delegate-performance-of-roslyn-sept-2012-ctp-is-impressive.aspx) and [this](http://piotrsowa.eu/2012/08/21/compileddelegatet-with-roslyn/) article, I'm trying to create a dynamic function with Roslyn.

However the mentioned sources are outdated or not complete and I'm not able to create a functional sample. My work so far:

```
var code = @"Func<int, int> doStuffToInt = i =>
{
   var result = i;
   for (var y = i; y <= i * 2; y++)
   {
      result += y;
   }
   return result;
};";


var se = new ScriptEngine();
var session = se.CreateSession();
session.AddReference(typeof(Program).Assembly);
session.AddReference(typeof(Expression).Assembly);

session.ImportNamespace("System");
session.ImportNamespace("System.Linq");
session.ImportNamespace("System.Linq.Expressions");

var submission = session.CompileSubmission<Func<int, int>>(code);

Func<int, int> myFunc =  submission.Execute();
```

However `myFunc` is always null and I'm not able to identify where the problem is. Can someone help me out to make this sample run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't actually used Roslyn in anger much at all.

Currently your code declares a variable, but doesn't do anything with it afterwards. Based on [this random blog post](http://blog.filipekberg.se/2011/12/08/hosted-execution-of-smaller-code-snippets-with-roslyn/), it looks like you possibly just need an extra expression after the declaration:

```
var code = @"Func<int, int> doStuffToInt = i =>
{
   var result = i;
   for (var y = i; y <= i * 2; y++)
   {
      result += y;
   }
   return result;
};
doStuffToInt"; // This is effectively the return statement for the script...
```

I don't guarantee it'll work, but give it a try :)

Comment: I'm confused. the last line is `doStuffToInt`, shouldn't that be a call to the func, such as `doStuffToInt(1);` or the like?

Comment: @HighCore: No, because the OP wants the result to be the function itself, not the result of *calling* the function.

Comment: @ChrisBallard: The semi-colon is needed - we're assigning a value (the string reference) to the `code` variable. The overall code snippet is just plain C#.

Comment: @JonSkeet AAAHH... that's right, so it's like `return doStuffToInt;` - I get it now.

Comment: hangs head in shame for doubting Jon Skeet :)