# c# convert a string into an expression

Tags: c#, expression

I have this interface:

```
interface ITransaction
{
    int Param1 { get; }

    int Param2 { get; }

    string Param3 { get; }

    string Param4 { get; }
}
```

Is there a way to convert the content of a string into an expression that is evaluating a parameter of type ITransaction and returns true or false?

I would like something like this:
the string : `"Param1 == 3 && Param3.Equals(\"test string\")"`

To be converted into an expression like :

```
bool Validate(ITransaction transaction)
{
      return transaction.Param1 == 3 && transaction.Param3.Equals("test string");
}
```

Can this be achieved by playing with expressions?

Comment: So you want to create source-code at runtime? This is quite broad, however there are plenty of sources around. Just search for them, e.g. create source-code at runtime from string.

Comment: to load this from a sql database, so I can make some dynamic rules....

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483213/create-a-func-with-roslyn) and see if this still works.

Comment: if you are loading rules from SQL, maybe it make sense to convert rules to SQL. implementation will be much simplier.

Comment: Fairly sure you'll have to design your own expression syntax and parse it yourself, and then evaluate the expression using Reflection.

Comment: Perhaps `System.Linq.Dynamic` might be useful? I've not used it before but I think it might be able to do what you are after.

Comment: @ASpirin I don't want to have domain logic inside sql layer because it's a little bit harder to have unit tests for that.

Comment: @BudaGavril it is your decision to store logic in SQL. The comment I gave is only related to a format of storage. Anyways it is clear what you mean. Good luck

Comment: I have done something similar using spring.net expression evaluator feature: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html